# Azure performance counters and scaling strategy?

Tags: azure

I have an azure cloud service that has high bursts of traffic sometimes at random intervals. These bursts of traffic can last 30 min to 1 hour.

I have signed up with paraleap - what kind of performance counters should I be looking at to ensure that my site stays responsive?

Thanks

Comment: How quickly do these bursts of traffic manifest themselves? What causes them (ie: is there anyway to predict their source, even if not using performance counters but some other magic indicator)?  What makes your application slow-down during these bursts - is it ram intensive, cpu intensive, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely broad! Only you (or the developer that wrote the application) can say what counters to monitor and when to scale.

However, for a typical ASP.NET application (that includes ASP.NET MVC) I would be looking at these perf. counters:

- Requests Rejected
- Requests Timed Out
- Requests Wait Time
- Requests Queued

If you want a good performing site, you definitely don't want rejected or timed out requests, right? Then probably you have to define what is reasonable "wait time" for the constraints of your application. And then you will want as few queued requests as possible.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will give you an overview of ASP.NET Performance counters and their explanation. Probably also providing some hints for your concrete scenario.